# Convert lines representing a term:definition dictionary into a Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have a file with lines defining terms and definitions for a dictionary.  I want to read them into a Python dictionary.  How do I do this?

```
abc:def
asdsdf:sdff,sdfs,sdfs
```

Desired output

```
{'abc':'def', 'asdsdf':'sdff','sdfs','sdfs'}
```

```
d = {}
open_file = open(i)
read = open_file.read()
(key,value) = read.split()
d[key] = value
print d
open_file.close()
```

Comment: Thats not a valid dictionary `{'abc':'def', 'asdsdf': ['sdff','sdfs','sdfs']}` is valid but what you have is not

Answer (score 2):

As @heinst correctly mentioned, your example dictionary is invalid. What you can do, however, is the following:

```
s = """abc:def
asdsdf:sdff,sdfs,sdfs"""
```

(For simplicity, I'm defining the multi-line string directly.)

```
print {line.split(":")[0]: line.split(":")[1] for line in s.split()}
```

Output:

```
{'abc': 'def', 'asdsdf': 'sdff,sdfs,sdfs'}
```

---

Or maybe this is more helpful for you:

```
print {line.split(":")[0]: line.split(":")[1].split(',') for line in s.split()}
```

Output:

```
{'abc': ['def'], 'asdsdf': ['sdff', 'sdfs', 'sdfs']}
```

Comment: Why not `dict(line.split(":") for line in s.split())`?

Comment: @PeterWood: Wow, that's nice! I wasn't aware of this way of initializing dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, the dictionary you want is not valid. You can do it this way:

```
i = 'test.txt'
with open(i, 'r') as open_file:
    d = {}
    read = open_file.read()
    l = read.split()
    for item in l:
        key, value = item.split(':')
        d[key] = value
    print d
```

Which will give:

```
{'abc': 'def', 'asdsdf': 'sdff,sdfs,sdfs'}
```

OR

```
i = 'test.txt'
with open(i, 'r') as open_file:
    d = {}
    read = open_file.read()
    l = read.split()
    for item in l:
        key, value = item.split(':')
        if ","  not in value:
            d[key] = value
        else:
            d[key] = value.split(',')
    print d
```

Which gives:

```
{'abc': 'def', 'asdsdf': ['sdff', 'sdfs', 'sdfs']}
```

Comment: Assuming it works for the OP, it's probably better to just store a one-element list for single-value keys, to keep the format of the dictionary uniform. Using `d[key] = value.split(',')` unconditionally results in  `{'abc': ['def'], 'asdsdf': ['sdff', 'sdfs', 'sdfs']}`

Comment: @chepner I do not get the result of `{'abc': ['def'], 'asdsdf': ['sdff', 'sdfs', 'sdfs']}` at all

Comment: You don't get `['def']` from `"def".split(",")`?

Comment: @chepner yes, but notice the if statement???? `if ","  not in value:`, so that doesnt happen....

Comment: I'm saying you don't need the if statement if you can standardize on making the value a list in every case, even if the list will only have one item.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do something like:

```
d = {}
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ':' in line:
            key, value = line.rstrip().split(':')
            d[key] = value.split(',') if ',' in value else value
```

Comment: Gives error: `key, value = line.split(':') ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

Comment: @heinst no it shouldn't, can I see your line?

Comment: I found out why, he has "line space line" in his file and yours is comprised of just "line line" with no space...the space in the file is causing the error

Comment: @heinst How can you know if there are blank lines? The OP said "dictionary lines" not blank lines. And the question is not properly formatted.

Comment: If you look at the lines he posted he has a line, then a blank line, then another line...I can assume he copied and pasted his file  or just made one that replicates the way his looks